# Почему на сайте созданным на битрикс, видны HTML тэги?

Tags: php, html, битрикс, cms

есть сайт созданный на битриксе (Аспро Максимум):
https://e-gifts.by/
Почему в секции О компании, на главной странице видны HTML тэги?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Их видно быть не должно, я всё перепроверил в плане корректности HTML.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно исправить.

Comment: Потому что есть ключ, например `['VALUE']` - который выведет HTML экранированный (как текст), а есть через тильду: `['~VALUE']`  - который выведет прям HTML.